# Adding/Removing field by using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, rdbms

I'm using Sequelize-cli and have some trouble with using it.

Note that it's my first time using Sequelize, might be I lost some concepts, will be very appreciate it told me what am I missing.

I made a simple model like this:

```
$ sequelize model:generate --name Notes --attributes text:content
```

And I get this migration file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Notes', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      content: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Notes');
  }
};
```

However now I need to add new field "title" the string type, but I can't find any related information about this process.

Should I just run *db:migrate:undo* to remove all tables and update migration & model file and redo the migration? I think this isn't proper way to using sequelize.

I'm also keep confusing the concept of "migration", why should I use this?

And it seems like all data is gone after run "migrate:undo" command, is there a way to save them so that I can restore the data after updating the table schema?

Any advice will very appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by create new migration and use queryInterface.addColumn to create new fields!

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
     return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Notes',
      'title',
      Sequelize.STRING
    );
  },
   down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   return queryInterface.removeColumn(
     'Notes',
     'title'
   );
  }
};
```